# How to sort 2D array values in ascending order in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

This is my basic PHP code. With only for loop and I want to sort it with this for loop *only*.

```
<?php
//this is my 2-d array
$arr=array(array(5,9),
        array(7,1),
        array(3,2),
        array(6,4),
        array(2,8));

/*my basic for loop concept*/
    for($k=0;$k<count($arr);$k++)//for loop for key
    {
        for($v=0;$v<count($arr[$k]);$v++)//for loop for value
        {
            for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)//for loop to iterate
            {
                for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)//for loop to iterate
                {
                    print_r($arr[$k][$v].'<br>');
                    if($arr[$k][$v] > $arr[$i][$j])
                    {
                    $temp = $arr[$k][$v];
                    $arr[$k][$v]=$arr[$i][$j];
                    $arr[$i][$j] = $temp;
                    print_r($arr[$i][$j].'<br>');
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please, show input data example and desired output.

Comment: Do you want output same here: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: my desired output:
$arr=array(array(1,2),
        array(2,3),
        array(4,5),
        array(6,7),
        array(8,9));

Comment: my simple input is:
Before sorting:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 8
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_multisort() function of PHP

For your code the solutions will be not to use loop.

```
<?php
    $arr=array(array(5,9),
        array(7,1),
        array(3,2),
        array(6,4),
        array(2,8));

    array_multisort($arr, SORT_ASC);     // For ascending
    array_multisort($arr, SORT_DESC);       // For Descending
    print_r($arr);
    ?>
```

If you want to sort sub-array also then you can use loop and can call array_multisort() function like

```
array_multisort($arr[$index], SORT_ASC);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: @ĐứcĐoànQuang: It will sort the array on basis of first element of the sub array

Comment: thanks for your help but i want to do it with only using for loop

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be help for you :

```
<?php
//this is my 2-d array
$arr=array(array(5,9),
        array(7,1),
        array(3,2),
        array(6,4),
        array(2,8));

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    array_multisort($arr[$i], SORT_ASC);
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: So do you want result in one array with sorting values?

Like 

Array(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2 etc.....